# Oracle Netsuite placeholder issue

Tags: netsuite

I have a question reagrding oracle Netsuite, we have integrated our website with oracle netsuite and when the user fill the web form, we are unable to get the complete information.

for ex; we have certain mandatory fields like first name, last name, company name, postal code etc.
i can only see first name and last and last in the automated email.

i have checked the placeholders and its correct. please find the screenshot and let me know if someone can help me in this [webform[placeholder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7hX9.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LP41E.png)

Can someone help me to receive all the information in the automated email